# Inconsistency between results in pagerank Networkx vs iGraph

Tags: python, igraph, networkx, pagerank

We are attempting to port a python application to .Net/Windows. The original application uses a NetworkX implementation of pagerank.

When we run the original code for the dataset below we get one set of results,  when we run what we believe is the same dataset using iGraph pagerank, we get a different result set.

Can anyone review the data below and give us some idea as to what might be causing the disconnect?

Starting Graph

```
From , To, Weight
------------------------------------------
[1, 2, 1.237635735532509]
[1, 3, 1.3176784432060453]
[2, 5, 0.1]
[2, 7, 1.6545276334003642]
[3, 0, 0.4013877113318902]
[3, 5, 0.9056698458264134]
[3, 7, 3.4462871026284194]
[4, 5, 0.9693717489378296]
[4, 7, 1.3176784432060453]
[5, 7, 1.6053605156578263]
[7, 2, 0.8068528194400547]
[7, 3, 0.9771288098085582]
[7, 4, 4.317678443206045]
[7, 5, 2.0108256237659905]
```

Results running Pagerank using NetworkX

```
0: 0.030658861877660655
1: 0.025151437717922904
2: 0.06899335192504014
3: 0.0767301059609998
4: 0.20435115331218195
5: 0.19799952556413375
7: 0.39611556364206074
```

Running Pagerank using iGraph

```
h = Graph()
h.add_vertices([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
h.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 1.237635735532509)
h.add_edge(1, 3, weight = 1.3176784432060453)
h.add_edge(2, 5, weight = 0.1)
h.add_edge(2, 7, weight = 1.6545276334003642)
h.add_edge(3, 0, weight = 0.4013877113318902)
h.add_edge(3, 5, weight = 0.9056698458264134)
h.add_edge(3, 7, weight = 3.4462871026284194)
h.add_edge(4, 5, weight = 0.9693717489378296)
h.add_edge(4, 7, weight = 1.3176784432060453)
h.add_edge(5, 7, weight = 1.6053605156578263)
h.add_edge(7, 2, weight = 0.8068528194400547)
h.add_edge(7, 3, weight = 0.9771288098085582)
h.add_edge(7, 4, weight = 4.317678443206045)                   
h.add_edge(7, 5, weight = 2.0108256237659905)

z = h.pagerank()
```

returns....

```
0.08263947646845539 
0.11209944263156851 
0.13863513488523824 
0.2088786898834253 
0.0909928717668216 
0.15533634946784883 
0.04713009918827309 
0.16428793570836897
```

`pagerank(None,True,.85,'weight',None,'prpack',1000,.001)` returns,

```
0.06306529189761995
0.1213272777521786
0.12419698504275958
0.21601479253860403
0.0845752983652644
0.10892203451714054
0.05260867410276095
0.22928964578367186
```

`pagerank(None,True,.85,'weight',None,'power',1000,.001)` returns,

```
0.05046861007484653
0.08032641955693953
0.1387381559084609
0.18249744338552665
0.10389267832310527
0.16623355776440546
0.019058750577540366
0.2587843844091753
```

Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of things leading to the differences in page rank. First, the `networkx` graph does not have node 6 (the isolate), but the `igraph` graph does. Second, make sure that the `igraph` graph is directed. When you do this, the page rank scores are nearly identical (at least out to the first 6th decimal place or so).

```
import igraph as ig
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) #Add node 6
G.add_edge(1, 2,weight= 1.237635735532509)
G.add_edge(1, 3,weight= 1.3176784432060453)
G.add_edge(2, 5,weight= 0.1)
G.add_edge(2, 7,weight= 1.6545276334003642)
G.add_edge(3, 0,weight= 0.4013877113318902)
G.add_edge(3, 5,weight= 0.9056698458264134)
G.add_edge(3, 7,weight= 3.4462871026284194)
G.add_edge(4, 5,weight= 0.9693717489378296)
G.add_edge(4, 7,weight= 1.3176784432060453)
G.add_edge(5, 7,weight= 1.6053605156578263)
G.add_edge(7, 2,weight= 0.8068528194400547)
G.add_edge(7, 3,weight= 0.9771288098085582)
G.add_edge(7, 4,weight= 4.317678443206045)
G.add_edge(7, 5,weight= 2.0108256237659905)

h = ig.Graph(directed = True)  #Ensure the graph is directed
h.add_vertices([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
h.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 1.237635735532509)
h.add_edge(1, 3, weight = 1.3176784432060453)
h.add_edge(2, 5, weight = 0.1)
h.add_edge(2, 7, weight = 1.6545276334003642)
h.add_edge(3, 0, weight = 0.4013877113318902)
h.add_edge(3, 5, weight = 0.9056698458264134)
h.add_edge(3, 7, weight = 3.4462871026284194)
h.add_edge(4, 5, weight = 0.9693717489378296)
h.add_edge(4, 7, weight = 1.3176784432060453)
h.add_edge(5, 7, weight = 1.6053605156578263)
h.add_edge(7, 2, weight = 0.8068528194400547)
h.add_edge(7, 3, weight = 0.9771288098085582)
h.add_edge(7, 4, weight = 4.317678443206045)                   
h.add_edge(7, 5, weight = 2.0108256237659905)
```

Now, checking page rank:

```
>>> h.pagerank(None,True,.85,'weight',None,'arpack')
[0.02990667328959136,
 0.02453435976169968,
 0.06730062757414129,
 0.07484756185358077,
 0.199337429914656,
 0.19314195829041825,
 0.02453435976169968,
 0.38639702955421296]
>>> nx.pagerank(G,alpha=0.85,weight = 'weight')
{0: 0.029906698992551148,
 1: 0.02453435614919296,
 2: 0.06730055444151634,
 3: 0.07484747242070261,
 4: 0.19933699472630276,
 5: 0.19314246522466136,
 6: 0.02453435614919296, #Here is node 6, missing from your example
 7: 0.3863971018958797}
```

One mystery to me is that the documentation for `networkx` says it uses the power method. However, using the power method for `igraph` produces different results. Using `arpack` or `prpack` produces substantially similar results.